# Problem in Z-Axis motion acceleration with MPU6050

Tags: accelerometer, gravity

I extracted motion acceleration with MPU6050 and removed gravity. Now, the problem is when I put the sensor in no-move status, I read nearly zero acceleration in z-axis but when I turn it 180 degree and then put it in the rest it shows nearly -2. There is a constant of 2 and I don't know how to remove it. I want the sensor to show me a zero acceleration when it is not moving.

Comment: Make it easy for your readers. Add a link to the datasheet for the device in question. There's a link button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You "removed gravity" from the Z axis by subtracting a constant. Obviously, this does not work if the Z axis no longer points "up".

If the sensor cannot be maintained in a particular orientation with respect to the gravity vector, then there is no simple way to remove gravity. You'll have to do a full 6-dimensional motion solution (3 axis accelerometer, 3-axis gyro) to determine position and attitude, and then derive your non-gravity accelerations from that.

Even then, your sensors will have long-term drift, so your solution will also need to have a means for compensating for that.

Comment: no i didn't subtract a constant, i remove gravity by using quaternion and rotation matrix and in the beginning of sensor working i see a zero motion acceleration and it's ok but when i turn it 180 deg , instead of showing zero again it shows -2.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your math. We can't help you unless you show it to us.

Comment: If gravity is removed, *something* is subtracting a constant somewhere.  If it's not you, it's the accelerometer.